# Spring Security Session Timeout - Clear Browser Cache

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-security, jboss5.x

I currently have a web application that is utilizing Spring Security hosted on a JBoss 5 server.

My issue is that if a user is idle for a few minutes then their session times out due to web.xml setting.  Once in a while they when try to hit the webapp when their session is invalid they get a 404 error.  The only way the browser can see the web app is when the user clears their browser cache.

Is there a way a fix for this so that the user doesn't have to clear out their browser cache?

Here is my spring security xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/import/trades" access="permitAll" />
    <!-- 
        The roles are prefix with the word ROLE 
        and it is upper case due to ldapAuthoritiesPopulator config section 
    -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_NBFIEPN_USERS', 'ROLE_NBFIEPN_DEVELOPERS')" />        

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>

    <security:logout />
</security:http>
```

Here's my web.xml file.  I have currently set the session timeout to 1 minute to replicate the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>TBA Web Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>horizon</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-service.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>horizon</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Session Timeout in minutes -->  
    <session-config> 
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> 
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this configuration to your spring security configuration

```
<security:http...>
   ...
  <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login"/>
</security:http>
```

Desription for `invalid-session-url` parameter:

> The URL to which a user will be redirected if they submit an invalid session indentifier. Typically used to detect session timeouts.

It should guid the user with an invalid session to the login page.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It actually turned out to be a JBoss server issue.  One of my JBoss server in the cluster was bad.